# How to optimize the rerendering of my code in React?

Tags: reactjs, optimization, slice

I have a react app that contains a component like this where I am displaying pages of data that are imported from a local json file:

```
import data from "data.json"

function myComponent() {
  const [pageInView, setPageInView] = useState(1);
  const [itemsOnPage, setItemsOnPage] = useState(15);
  const indexFinalItem = pageInView * itemsOnPage;
  const indexFirstItem = indexFinalItem - itemsOnPage;
  const itemsToDisplay = data.slice(
    indexFirstItem,
    indexFinalItem
  );

  --- rest of component ---
}
```

The feedback I have got on this section of code is that I “can avoid recalculating (slicing) on every render by placing the data in a state”.
I am having trouble understanding this and wondering if anyone could expand a bit on the optimization of this code?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the *data alone* into state wouldn't really help - it's never recalculated from the JSON, after all. The issue is that the `.slice` occurs every render. A better approach than state to keep this from being done every time would be to use `useMemo`.

```
const itemsToDisplay = useMemo(() => {
  const indexFinalItem = pageInView * itemsOnPage;
  const indexFirstItem = indexFinalItem - itemsOnPage;
  return data.slice(
    indexFirstItem,
    indexFinalItem
  );
}, [pageInView, itemsOnPage]);
```

This way, those calculations including the `.slice` occur only when `pageInView` or `itemsOnPage` change.